# Pandas - Comparing two Dataframes and finding rows that have changed

Tags: pandas

I have two snapshots of a Dataframe taken at different time. I am trying to find rows that are different in these two Dataframes. Technically any row can change.

Snapshot 1:

```
prod_id, prod_name, sale, price_per_unit
prod_a, prod_name_a, 10, 20
prod_b, prod_name_b, 4, 3
prod_c, prod_name_c, 3, 10
prod_d, prod_name_d, 5, 4
```

Snapshot 2:

```
prod_id, prod_name, sale, price_per_unit
prod_a, prod_name_a, 10, 20
prod_b, prod_name_b, 14, 13
prod_c, prod_name_c, 5, 1
prod_d, prod_name_d, 7, 2
```

I am trying to have these compared and return back rows that have changed.

**Expected output:**

```
prod_id, prod_name, sale, price_per_unit, source
prod_b, prod_name_b, 4, 3, snapshot_1
prod_b, prod_name_b, 14, 13, snapshot_2
prod_c, prod_name_c, 3, 10, snapshot_1
prod_c, prod_name_c, 5, 1, snapshot_2
prod_d, prod_name_d, 5, 4, snapshot_1
prod_d, prod_name_d, 7, 2, snapshot_2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare all values by [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) and [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) (necessary same index and same columns in both DataFrames) and then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with new columns by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), sorting and last create default index:

```
mask = df1.ne(df2).any(axis=1)

df = pd.concat([df1[mask].assign(source = 'snapshot_1'), 
                df2[mask].assign(source = 'snapshot_2')]
       ).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)

print (df)
  prod_id    prod_name  sale  price_per_unit      source
0  prod_b  prod_name_b     4               3  snapshot_1
1  prod_b  prod_name_b    14              13  snapshot_2
2  prod_c  prod_name_c     3              10  snapshot_1
3  prod_c  prod_name_c     5               1  snapshot_2
4  prod_d  prod_name_d     5               4  snapshot_1
5  prod_d  prod_name_d     7               2  snapshot_2
```

Comment: thanks that worked. However if a row is blank in both the DataFrames for the same column it pulls both these rows whereas it should not really pull this as a difference in values.. Is there anyway we can add that to the above code..

Comment: @scottmartin - yes, then use trick - replace to same values misisng values -  `mask = df1.fillna(0).ne(df2.fillna(0)).any(axis=1)`